# How do I replicate content on a web farm

Tags: iis, replication, webserver

We have a Windows Server Web Edition 2003 Web Farm.

What can we use that handles replication across the servers for:

Content & IIS Configuration (App Pools, Virtual Directories, etc...)

We will be moving to Windows 2008 in the near future, so I guess what options are there on Windows 2008 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into [Windows Distributed File System](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/techinfo/overview/dfs.mspx).  It should be supported by both Windows Server 2003 & 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Distributed File System (DFS) is good for content, especially if each server (or a number of servers) host a replica synced up with File Replication Service (FRS). So if you've got two servers, each has a complete replica, so one going down doesn't mean the site goes down.

If all servers in your 'cluster' will host a replica, the home directory in IIS can be configured to go against the local drive (e.g., D:). If you have more servers than replicas, then you should use the DFS mount point (\domainname\dfsmountpointname).